# "Unclosed client session"

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot for my discord server that will hand out roles when a certain command is said. (It's an anime server and the chats for each show are only available if you have the rank)

I was looking around this website and I just copied and pasted the code and filled in the blanks like a noob. Here's the code:

```
    import discord
    from discord.utils import get

    client = discord.Client()

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return
        if message.content == '!SAO':
            role = get(message.server.roles, name='SAO Fan')
            await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        if message.content == '!AOT':
            role = get(message.server.roles, name='AOT Fan')
            await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        if message.content == '!7DS':
            role = get(message.server.roles, name='7DS Fan')
            await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        if message.content == '!naruto':
            role = get(message.server.roles, name='Naruto Fan')
            await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        if message.content == '!BNHA':
            role = get(message.server.roles, name='BNHA Fan')
            await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        if message.content == '!FairyTail':
            role = get(message.server.roles, name='Fairy Tail Fan')
            await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
    client.run=('token')
```

When I run the .py file, it doesn't work and when I put it through the command prompt it says
"Unclosed client session"
"client.session: "

Comment: Try removing `=` from `client.run=('token')`

Answer (score -1):

The issue is documented here:

https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/398

there is no = in client.run(token)

and

Maybe you need to run `client.close()` as well